# Pyasn1 nested sequence - incompatible tags

Tags: python, asn.1, pyasn1

I need help with my code. I have two structs, which are using third.

```
class Bar(univ.Sequence):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
    namedtype.NamedType('first',univ.Integer().subtype(implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext,tag.tagFormatSimple,0))),
    namedtype.NamedType('second',univ.Integer().subtype(implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 1)))
    )

class Foo(univ.Sequence):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
    namedtype.OptionalNamedType('test', Bar().subtype(implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext,tag.tagFormatSimple,3))),
    )

class Foo1(univ.Sequence):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
    namedtype.OptionalNamedType('test', Bar().subtype(implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext,tag.tagFormatSimple,2))),
    )
```

So, in the class Foo, Bar has a tag [3] and in the class Foo1 e.g. [2]. If only I had one class I would do

```
tagSet = tagBaseSet = tag.initTagSet(tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext,tag.tagFormatSimple,3))
```

in the bar class (and it's working). But how do I cope with that kind of problem?
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Here's asn1 representation:

```
Bar     ::= SEQUENCE {
first           [0] INTEGER,
second          [1] INTEGER
}

Foo     ::= SEQUENCE {
  first             [0] INTEGER,
  second            [1] INTEGER OPTIONAL,
  third             [2] INTEGER OPTIONAL,
  bar               [3] Bar
}

Foo1    ::= SEQUENCE {
  first             [0] INTEGER,
  second            [1] INTEGER OPTIONAL,
  bar               [2] Bar
}
```

EDIT2: Code: run and then delete comments (I get incompatible tags. Without tagSet in Bar, in both cases, too):

```
from pyasn1.type import univ,namedtype,tag

class Bar(univ.Sequence):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
    namedtype.NamedType('first',univ.Integer().subtype(implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext,tag.tagFormatSimple,0))),
    namedtype.NamedType('second',univ.Integer().subtype(implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatSimple, 1)))
    )
    tagSet = tagBaseSet = tag.initTagSet(tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext,tag.tagFormatConstructed,3))

class Foo(univ.Sequence):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
    namedtype.OptionalNamedType('test', Bar().subtype(implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext,tag.tagFormatSimple,3))),
    )

class Foo1(univ.Sequence):
    componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(
    namedtype.OptionalNamedType('test', Bar().subtype(implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext,tag.tagFormatSimple,2))),
    )

bar = Bar()
bar.setComponentByName('first',1)
bar.setComponentByName('second',2)

fo = Foo()
fo.setComponentByName('test',bar)

# fo1 = Foo1()
# fo1.setComponentByName('test',bar)

print fo.prettyPrint()
# print fo1.prettyPrint()
```

Comment: Could you please describe in more details what exactly is your problem? Is it about selecting matching class (Foo/Foo1) based on the input? BTW, I guess you should be using  "tagFormatConstructed" when tagging constructed types such as SEQUENCE.

Comment: Ok so if I want to create an object e.g. Foo bar has an ID nr 3, so to avoid incompatible tag error  I need to set tag in Bar with tagID 3, am I right?
So then when I want to create Foo1 there's error cause in Foo1 bar has a tag nr 2.
If I'm wrong somewhere, please correct me, cause I'm total newbie in asn1 :P.
P.S. what's the difference between constructed and simple? Is it only convention, because I didn't notice any changes when I replaced few tags with constructed?

Comment: So far I do not see where tag incompatibility may possibly happen. I run your code and it seems to work. To help you I'd need an exact use case / code snippet which fails.